# Not able to match field from get_user_model in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am working on a Books inventory project, where users can add their books and others can see  them.

What I'm trying on home page to show all the books, but only the owner will see the 'Edit' and 'Delete' options. Others will see 'View Details' Option.

I've used get_user_model() feature of  Django to get the owner of the book when the user adds new book:

```
...
class Book(models.Model):
    title =models.CharField(max_length =255)
    author =models.CharField(max_length =255)
    genre =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
    owner =models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete =models.CASCADE,)
...
```

Now when I'm mapping the username of the user and the owner of the book, It's not working.
This id the HTML template:

```
...
{% for book in object_list %}
<div class="card">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{book.title}}</span> 
    <span class="font-weight-bold">by {{book.author}}</span>
    <span class="text-muted">Genre: {{book.genre}}</span>
    <span class="text-muted">Owner: {{book.owner}}</span>
    <span class="text-muted">User: {{user.username}}</span>
    <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
        {% if user.username == book.owner  %}
         <a href ="{% url 'book_edit' book.pk %}">Edit</a> | <a href="{% url 'book_delete' book.pk %}">Delete</a>
         {% else %}
         <a href="#">Show Details</a>
         {% endif %}
        </div>
</div>
<br />
{% endfor %}
...
```

I'm bringring both the username and owner seprately too for comparison.
Still I'm getting show details for all the books.

[image]

For Debugging I also tried equating both 'user.username' and 'book.owner' to 'jitesh2796' . Though the former works but the latter does not. So I guess the problem is somewhere in the django field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
{% if request.user == book.owner %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

But nevertheless filtering in a *template* is *not* a good idea. You should filter in the view, such that the filtering can happen at the database level. For example with:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BookListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Book
    # …

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            owner=self.request.user
        )
```

> **Note**: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) advises to
>   use the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) over
>   [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).
>   This is safer, since if the authentication app is not yet loaded, the settings
>   can still specify the name of the model. Therefore it is better to write:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     # …
>     owner = models.ForeignKey(
>         settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE
>     )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update condition in the template

```
{% if user.username == book.owner.username  %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Still wanted to understand how it works as I don't see any username attribute of the owner.

Comment: The User Model has a many fields like first_name, last_name, username, etc...

in the foreign-key you can access all the fields of user model like this:
`owner.first_name, owner.last_name, owner.user_name`.

if you have a foreign key of a particular model so you can access all the fields like USER_MODEL.

for more information please follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/